# log4j-1.2 fails to rollover(new files not created)

Tags: java, log4j

This issue occurs when i my application have "Too Many open files" at the rollover time with exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
      org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
```

This does not recover(as in new files not created) even when FD becomes available.
Is there a way to recover automatically(i.e. new files created and log emitted) from this problem when FD becomes available ? Can i do some kind of exception handling to get over this issue?
Note: For my Case i do not want to increase FD limit.

Comment: can you share the complete stacktrace? Does the error come from your class?

Comment: @aran : Won't be able to share complete stacktrace. But Yes Error come from my class

Comment: Then simply catch any logger operation. The issue is related to your class sending a null argument to the logger. Identify where it happens and try-catch it

Comment: @aran : Sorry for not being clear. The error comes from DailyRollingFileAppender which calls the subAppend method which even on rollover failure(due to setFile error), it eventually sends a null argument through super.subAppend(event); for which there is no exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [javadocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html#subAppend(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent)) from the **`WriterAppender`**, this is shown related to the method that's throwing the error:

> **`protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event)`**
>
> *Actual writing occurs here. Most subclasses of WriterAppender **will need to override
> this method**.*

As you commented, **`DailyRollingFileAppender`** overrides this but also calls super , invoking the `WriterAppender`'s *`subAppend()`* at the end of its execution ([**Source code**](https://github.com/kikonen/log4j-share/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.java))

---

***DailyRollingFileAppender***

[image]

---

***WriteAppender***

[image]

My guess is that the yellow marked line is the responsible of this, as result of `event` or some of its fields being *`null`*.

---

### *Possible solution*

You could implement your own extension of the `DailyRollingFileAppender`, in order to check for nulls or just enclose it within a try-catch block in order to avoid your current scenario: the exception is not catched and propagates until stopping the whole process.

This is just an example and you'd have to implement it based on your needs and the knowledge of the error you have; So just take it as a base.

The point would be extending from the appender and overriding the subAppend method. This way, you'll be able to manage the exceptions properly.

```
public class FailHandlerRollingAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender 
{     
    @Override
    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) 
    { 
       try
       {    
          boolean correctEvent=false;
         /*check if event is null, or any field is null, for example.
          If needed, also modify the event as you wish, before calling super.
          Enclosing it in a try-catch block would avoid the uncontrolled exception.
          All your logic you need to include here.*/
         
          if (correctEvent)
              super.subAppend(event);
        }  
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
           //...
        }
     }    
}
```

The last step would be declaring it as appender in your configuration file (*this depends on the log4j version used, but is similar somehow on all of them*). Just an example:

```
 //...
<appender name="FailHandlerRollingAppender" class="x.y.pack.FailHandlerRollingAppender">
     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
     <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
     <param name="File" value="mine.log"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
     </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FailHandlerRollingAppender"/>
 </root>
 //...
```

---

Overriding the problematic `subAppend()` should let you manage this scenario; At least, you'd be able to avoid the unmanaged exception propagation, and from there, handle the specific error prone scenarios.

Comment: I was thinking this, but needed the guidance. Thanks for putting this together. I will try this and update the question :)

Comment: Maybe this also helps; A custom rollingappender overriding the rollOver method: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-rotation-example/